# Similar Queries, different sums

Tags: sql

I am attempting to join a table of orders with a product info table so that I can create a table with all of the orders so I can break earnings down by the available dimensions, but each query I run has a different total sum.

My tables look as such:

Orders table: id, date, product name, quantity ordered
   Product table: id, name, type, artist, sku, price, visibility, product type

Each of these queries produces a different total, and I just want to understand why.

Query 1:

```
select sum(subtotal) 
from (select orders.date, orders."product name", 
  orders."quantity ordered", products."product type", products.price,
  products.artist, ("quantity ordered"*price) AS "subtotal"
from orders
LEFT JOIN products ON orders."product name"=products.name)
```

Query 2:

```
select sum(subtotal) 
from (select orders.date, orders."product name", 
  orders."quantity ordered", products."product type", products.price,
  products.artist, ("quantity ordered"*price) AS "subtotal"
from orders
LEFT JOIN products ON orders."product name"=products.name)
Group by orders.id, orders.date, orders."product name", orders."quantity 
         ordered", products."product type", products.price, products.artist, subtotal
```

And when I export both tables and find the sum with a VLOOKUP to at the price in, I get a different answer than both of those queries.

Assuming the queries are creating duplicates, but having trouble tracing my error.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?
Waht's your dbms?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're selecting `orders.id` in your subquery. Therefore attempting to group by `orders.id` could be causing errors (some DBMS's wouldn't even allow it)